# Merge Sort Recursion

Tags: java, algorithm, mergesort

This is a code from Introduction to Java Programming about Merge Sort. This method uses a recursion implementation.

```
public class MergeSort {
  2    /** The method for sorting the numbers */
  3    public static void mergeSort(int[] list) {
  4      if (list.length > 1) {
  5        // Merge sort the first half
  6        int[] firstHalf = new int[list.length / 2];
  7        System.arraycopy(list, 0, firstHalf, 0, list.length / 2);
  8        mergeSort(firstHalf);
  9  
 10        // Merge sort the second half
 11        int secondHalfLength = list.length - list.length / 2;
 12        int[] secondHalf = new int[secondHalfLength];
 13        System.arraycopy(list, list.length / 2,
 14          secondHalf, 0, secondHalfLength);
 15        mergeSort(secondHalf);
 16  
 17        // Merge firstHalf with secondHalf into list
 18        merge(firstHalf, secondHalf, list);
 19      }
 20    }
```

**My question:** is in Line 8 calls the recursion method back to "mergeSort"? If running from the beginning of the method, the "firstHalf" array will be created again and the length will be half short. I think the "firstHalf" can not created again and the length should not be changed if an array is defined already.

Here is the whole code link: [Merge Sort Java](http://www.cs.armstrong.edu/liang/intro9e/html/MergeSortWithLineNumber.html?).

Comment: `firstHalf` will be created again as it it belongs to the scope of `(list.length > 1)` so for every call to `MergeSort` with a `list.length > 1` you will get another `int[] firstHalf`.  That was your question or?

Comment: I encourage you to look at this link http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/22mergesort/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is beginner's way of thinking. Yes, exactly I thought the same when I encountered this before. I couldn't believe that the same array size can change dynamically. Understand this, in the below code, `array l and array r` are created with different sizes for `every recursive call`. Don't confuse on this.

Yes, this is never possible that the same array size changes dynamically for a beginner like you and me. But, there is an exception, well, there are exceptions. We will see them very often as we move forward.

> Its recursion, in recursion things change dynamically and all this
>   changes are stored in a call stack.

Its confusing but its really interesting if you ponder over it. Its profound. Merge sort can be implemented in quite different ways, but the underlying concept of recursion is same. Don't get confused here, Its better you follow another way to do it, [video:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TzeBrDU-JaY)

Merge sort first takes a list or an array. Lets imagine the

```
a.length; #lenght of an array is 8
```

Now the end goal is to split the array recursively, till it reaches to a point where there are no-elements (**only-one**). And a `single element is always sorted`.

**See the base case in the below code:**

```
if(a.length<2) /*Remember this is the base case*/
        {
            return;
        }
```

Once it reaches to single element, sort and merge them back. This way you get a complete sorted array which is easy to merge. The only reason we are doing all this non-sense is to get a better run-time algorithm which is **O(nlogn).**

Because, all the other sorting algos (`insertion, bubble, and selection`) will take **O(n2)**, which is alot, too much indeed. So, humanity must figure out the better solution. Its a need for humanity, very important. I know its annoying, I had gone through this non-sense.

Please do some research on recursion before you attempt on this. Understand recursion clearly. Keep all this away. Take a simple recursion example and start working on it. Take a factorial example. Its a bad example but its easy to understand.

### Top-down MergeSort

See my code, its nice and easy. Again, both are not easy to understand on your first attempt. You must get in touch with recursion before you attempt to understand these things. All the very best.

```
public class MergeSort 
{
    private int low;
    private int high;
    private int mid;
    public static int[] a;

    public MergeSort(int x)
    {
        a = new int[x];
        a[0]=19;
        a[1]=10;
        a[2]=0;
        a[3]=220;
        a[4]=80;
        a[5]=2000;
        a[6]=56001;
        a[7]=2;

    }

    public void division(int[] a)
    {
        low=0;
        int p;
        high = a.length;
        mid = (high+low)/2;
        if(a.length<2) /*Remember this is the base case*/
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            int[] l = new int[mid];
            int[] r = new int[high-mid];
            /*copying elements from a into l and r*/
            for(p=0;p<mid;p++)
                l[p]=a[p];
            for(int q=0;q<high-mid;q++, p++)
                r[q]=a[p];
            /*first recursive call starts from here*/
            division(l);
            division(r); 
            sortMerge(a, l, r);
        }
    }

    public void sortMerge(int[] a, int[] l, int[] r)
    {

        int i=0, j=0, k=0;
        /*sorting and then merging recursively*/
        while(i<l.length && j<r.length)
            {
                if(l[i]<r[j])
                    {
                        a[k] = l[i]; /*copying sorted elements into a*/ 
                        i++;
                        k++;
                    }
                else
                    {
                        a[k] = r[j];
                        j++;
                        k++;
                    }
            }

        /*copying remaining elements into a*/
        while(i<l.length)
            {
                a[k] = l[i];
                i++;
                k++;
            }

        while(j<r.length)
            {
                a[k] = r[j];
                j++;
                k++;
            }

    }
    /*method display elements in an array*/
    public void display()
    {
        for(int newIndex=0;newIndex<a.length;newIndex++)
        {
        System.out.println(a[newIndex]);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        MergeSort obj = new MergeSort(8);
        obj.division(a);
        obj.display();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To understand how Merge Sort works you must understand two core data structures, Arrays and Stacks. Stacks are LIFO (Last in First Out). Method calls are executed using Stacks, so the last method call is executed first. Due to these factors, the Merge Sort has this unique behavior.

For example let's take an array as an input:

```
int[] input = new array[] {12, 11, 13, 5, 6, 7};
```

Now let's implement a Merge Sort on this array:

'''

```
class MergeSort
{


  
    private static void merge_sort(int[] arr)
    {


        if (arr.length > 1)
        {
            int midpoint = arr.length / 2;

            int[] l_arr = new int[midpoint];
            int[] r_arr = new int[arr.length - midpoint];




            int L_index = 0;
            int R_index = 0;







// SORTING [ BEGIN ]



           
            // [ BEGIN ]
            // WHILE LOOP THAT IS FILLING THE LEFT ARRAY
            //

            while(L_index < l_arr.length )
            {
                l_arr[L_index] = arr[L_index];

                if (L_index + 1 < l_arr.length)
                {
                    l_arr[L_index + 1] = arr[L_index + 1];
                    L_index++;
                }

                L_index++;
            }


            // [ END ]






            L_index = midpoint;






            // [ BEGIN ]
            // A WHILE LOOP THAT IS FILLING THE RIGHT ARRAY
            //


            while(R_index < r_arr.length)
            {
                r_arr[R_index] = arr[L_index];

                if (R_index + 1 < r_arr.length)
                {
                    r_arr[R_index + 1] = arr[L_index + 1];
                    L_index++;
                    R_index++;
                }


                L_index++;
                R_index++;

            }

            // [ END ]






            merge_sort(l_arr);
            merge_sort(r_arr);


// SORTING [ END ]






// MEGING [ BEGIN ]

            int l_index = 0;
            int r_index = 0;
            int index = 0;


            while (l_index < l_arr.length && r_index < r_arr.length )
            {
                if (l_arr[l_index] <= r_arr[r_index])
                {
                    arr[index] = l_arr[l_index];
                    l_index++;
                }
                else
                {
                    arr[index] = r_arr[r_index];
                    r_index++;
                }

                index++;
            }



            while (l_index < l_arr.length)
            {
                arr[index] = l_arr[l_index];
                l_index++;
                index++;
            }


            while (r_index < r_arr.length)
            {
                arr[index] = r_arr[r_index];
                r_index++;
                index++;
            }

// MEGING [ END ]

        }


    }







    

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        int[] arr = new int[] {12, 11, 13, 5, 6, 7};




        // BEGIN THE MERGE SORT
        merge_sort(arr);
    }

}
```

'''

When the merge sort is called the array is split into two arrays, the left array and right array. When the split happens, the left and right arrays are filled, and then recursion occurs.

[image]

The split happens always on the left until no split cannot be done, then the split transitions to the right half.

[image]

When the array reaches the size of one, the recursion stops, giving control to the previous method call. When no recursion cannot be performed, the code execution will go bellow the recursive method calls and the merge section of the algorithm will arrange the two halves in increasing / decreasing order and pass the control back to its own caller method instance.

Now the magic happens. When the array is given as a parameter to a method and it is sorted, the modifications done on the array parameter will affect the array that is within the caller method instance because, arrays are passed by reference and not by value. So this means that each time recursion occurs and it is passing the left or right half of the array, it is passing a reference to the left or right array and the modifications done by the called method instance will affect the array passed as a parameter in the caller method.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As it was pointed out by Emz: This is due to scope reasons. A local variable is a new object. 
[

> Local variables are declared by local variable declaration statements
>   (§14.4).
>
> Whenever the flow of control enters a block (§14.2) or for statement
>   (§14.14), a new variable is created for each local variable declared
>   in a local variable declaration statement immediately contained within
>   that block or for statement.
>
> A local variable declaration statement may contain an expression which
>   initializes the variable. The local variable with an initializing
>   expression is not initialized, however, until the local variable
>   declaration statement that declares it is executed. (The rules of
>   definite assignment (§16) prevent the value of a local variable from
>   being used before it has been initialized or otherwise assigned a
>   value.) The local variable effectively ceases to exist when the
>   execution of the block or for statement is complete.][1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.3)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative implementation of merge sort, this is `bottom-up MergeSort`

```
public class MergeSort {
public static void merge(int[]a,int[] aux, int f, int m, int l) {

    for (int k = f; k <= l; k++) {
        aux[k] = a[k];
    }

    int i = f, j = m+1;
    for (int k = f; k <= l; k++) {
        if(i>m) a[k]=aux[j++];
        else if (j>l) a[k]=aux[i++];
        else if(aux[j] > aux[i]) a[k]=aux[j++];
        else a[k]=aux[i++];
    }       
}
public static void sort(int[]a,int[] aux, int f, int l) {
    if (l<=f) return;
    int m = f + (l-f)/2;
    sort(a, aux, f, m);
    sort(a, aux, m+1, l);
    merge(a, aux, f, m, l);
}
public static int[] sort(int[]a) {
    int[] aux = new int[a.length];
    sort(a, aux, 0, a.length-1);
    return a;
}
}
```